# MPI - Will it cause any problems if a message sent by MPI_Bcast() is not received in one of the nodes (doesn't call MPI_Bcast)

Tags: mpi

I have a master node that broadcasts a message every so often using MPI_Bcast. Problem is, I have one specific node that needs to run a bit slower than the others, and say, it will only participate in the bcast half of the time. So its like:

```
// -- iteration 1
Master: MPI_Bcast(msg1)
Node1: MPI_Bcast(msg1)
Node2: MPI_Bcast(msg1)
Node0: MPI_Bcast(msg1)

// -- iteration 2
Master: MPI_Bcast(msg2)
Node1: MPI_Bcast(msg2)
Node2: MPI_Bcast(msg2)
Node0: DoSomethingImportantAndDontParticipateInBcast()

// -- iteration 3
Master: MPI_Bcast(msg3)
Node1: MPI_Bcast(msg3)
Node2: MPI_Bcast(msg3)
Node0: MPI_Bcast(msg3)
```

Is this possible? Note that in the last iteration, I want Node0 to receive msg3 and not msg2 (which it ignored).

Comment: *send* and *broadcast* mean different things in MPI, and there is a variety of types of send. Please explain more.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I've updated the question. thanks. tbh, I'm not sure that I entirely understand broadcasting in MPI so please do let me know if I'm missing something (I hope I'm not)

Comment: This is an erroneous program.  MPI collectives must be called collectively.  End of story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suggested pattern won't work, all processes in a communicator participate in each broadcast.

If you were to implement your plan as it stands you would find that `node0` matches `MPI_Bcast(msg3)` with the broadcast that other processes see as `MPI_Bcast(msg2)`.  There is no mechanism for identifying broadcasts separately.  It's a long time since I wrote an MPI program with mis-matched broadcasts so I can't recall exactly what happens, and I'm not sure what the standard requires.  Generally I expect bad things to happen, possibly all the processes which have participated in more broadcasts than the special one grind to a halt to wait.

What you could do is to define an *intracommunicator*, using `mpi_comm_create`, which excludes `node0` and call broadcasts on both the global communicator and the new one as you wish.